# Access images and css files in WAMP

Tags: html, css, wamp

I have created folder structure as www/xyz/images and other folder www/xyz/css. I am importing the css file and css file as following code. My background image is not displayed when I am importing css file.

index.php
//

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainpage.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<h1></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

mainpage.css
//

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/foodspot4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images path have to be relative to the directory of the CSS file. By calling `images/foodspot4.jpg` you are asking the stylesheet to look for the file in the directory `www/xyz/css/images`, which does not exist.

Therefore, you should use relative paths: it should be as follow...

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/foodspot4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

`../` will instruct the CSS to look for the `/images/` folder in the parent directory. [Here's a quick article explaining how relative file path works.](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)